# Free FORTRAN compiler - or one that does not have to be updated all the time

Tags: xcode, development

I have paid some good money to buy the "Intel Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for Fortran OS X" - The problem is that, whenever the OS changes (i.e., from Lion to Mountain Lion to Mavericks to Yosemite), the compiler needs update, and purchase of a new version. (Unless you buy a maintenance, approx. $300/yr). Also, sometimes a new version is required even when Xcode is updated!

Two questions:

1. Is there some free FORTRAN compiler or a non-free, which works after updates of Xcode or/and OS?
2. Is there a way to make it work, even if is was destined for say Mavericks?

Comment: If you need any Intel compiler you probably do need the maintenance and if you do need it $300/yr is low cost - it will be less than what a professional developer costs for a day including all overheads like benefits, design machines etc )

Comment: See http://www.macinchem.org/reviews/fortran/fortran.php for a list of others and Homebrew instructions

Answer (score 3):

re free Fortran compilers

[gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/) is part of gcc (gcc stands for GNU Compiler Collection not just the name of GNU's c++ compiler)

Xcode now does not install gcc (even via command line tools) gcc is a link or wrapper to clang

As to installation my first attempt would be via a package manager like Macports or Homebrew or fink.

For macports (others will be similar) install will be

1. Install macports as per the [guide](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. install gcc with the fortran option `sudo port install gcc5`
3. install a select program to allow selection of different gcc versions (in this case there will only be one) `sudo port install gcc_select`
4. select the version `sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc5`

gfortran is now in /opt/local/bin

Macports should download readymade binaries for this so no wait for a long compile of gcc

If you upgrade the OS Macports will need a complete reinstallation (OK it might work but support and test is only done on a complete reinstallation, previous OS upgrades have definitely needed one the last 1-2 might have worked)

Homebrew instructions are included in this [article](https://www.macinchem.org/reviews/fortran/fortran.php) which also includes other free Fortran compilers and other useful Fortran info.

Answer (score 1):

University of Southern California's  Laboratory of Applied Pharmacokinetics (LAPK) has GFortran for Mac OS 10.13 http://www.lapk.org/gfortran/gfortran.php?OS=7 in case anyone is still thinking of installing it.

Disclaimer: I haven't installed it yet so I don't know how it will go.